# Click away listener with select component as a child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

In example below there is container that contains few elements. Everything works fine instead of nested Select element. When clicking select, it detects as if the click happened outside the red container

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-snowflake-d89ncp?file=/demo.tsx)

Comment: maybe leave some margin for the select

Comment: There still will be problem with clicking directly on select component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue goes away if you use `disablePortal` on the `Select`. The reason is: by default mui uses a portal concept, which means popups are placed into a completely different DOM sub-tree (located as last child in the `<body>`). Well this royally messes with checking if bubbling events originated in the same subtree constituted by your component or are considered *outside* clicks.

```
          <Select
            labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
            id="demo-simple-select"
            value={age}
            label="Age"
            onChange={handleChange}
            MenuProps={{disablePortal: true}}
          >
            <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
          </Select>
```

Comment: Just my personal opinion:  I don't think MUI's default behavior is a good default behavior. And further: mui is too convoluted, is too opinionated, and makes it difficult to work with.
I struggled a while with mui and came to the conclusion that it's not worth it.